# Strange array constructor behavior with forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

*I accidentally stumbled across the following array behavior while working on my website that I can't really wrap my head around.* 

If I write something like this in my script:

```
Array(4).forEach(function(elem) {console.log(elem);});
```

I return no log entries, or anything for that matter. 

**On the contrary,** if I write this instead:

```
[undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined].forEach(function(elem) {console.log(elem);});
```

I do in fact get 4 log entries. 

***My question is***, why is this? Why would I not get log entries for the array constructor but get them using `[]`?  Neither the  [constructor specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.2.2)  nor the  [`forEach` specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18)   really elude to `undefined` or help me understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MDN on `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> `forEach()` executes the provided callback once for each element **present** in the array in ascending order. It is not invoked for indexes **that have been deleted or elided**. However, it is executed for elements that are **present and have the value undefined**.

The way you're initializing the array does set it's length, but doesn't set the values in the array to anything, so `forEach` doesn't iterate over those elements:

> If the argument `len` is a Number and `ToUint32(len)` is equal to `len`, then the length property of the newly constructed object is set to `ToUint32(len)`.

Example:

```js
var a = Array(5);

a.forEach(function(element){
  console.log('First log:', element)
});

a[2] = true;
a[3] = undefined;

a.forEach(function(element){
  console.log('Second log:', element)
});

var b = [];
b[999] = 'Foobar';

b.forEach(function(element){
  console.log('Third log:', element)
});
```

As you can see in the console, it simply skips over indexes that have no value set.

Comment: That makes much more sense, I just figured initializing the array would default set the values to be undefined. Many thanks!